# Intuitively, what are eigenvectors/values in a graph?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I am having a hard time understanding what eigenvectors and values intuitively represent in an adjacency matrix in a graph problem. I understand in a linear transformation, eigenvectors are vectors that are only scaled after the transform is applied and that the eigenvalues are those scale factors.

Is it strictly for computational efficiency that we are so interested in the eigenvalues in graph theory, so we can utilize the eigenbasis for computations?

Comment: I understand your frustration with this. I've posed almost this same question to just about every graph theorist I run into, and the consensus seems to be that there isn't a single 'nice' interpretation of graph eigenvalues. 

There are, however, conclusions we can draw about a graph when we know something about its spectrum (collection of eigenvalues). For instance, if a graph $G$ is bipartite then its spectrum is symmetric about 0.  The largest eigenvalue of a graph can tell you about the connectivity of the graph and the second largest eigenvalue gives some structural insights.

Comment: I really appreciate the insight! Could you elaborate a tad more or send me to a link that could? I cannot find a lot of information readily available to look more into this.

When you say the spectrum is symmetric, you mean the eigenvalues would be symmetric about the 0th element in the vector of eigenvalues?

I'd love to read more into the connectivity and structural insights as well.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have clarified what I mean by symmetric. In this case it means that for each positive eigenvalue there is a negative eigenvalue. Say you have a bipartite graph with twelve. eigenvalues and you know that four of them are 0. That leaves eight  non-zero eigenvalues, four of which must be positive and four which must be negative.

I don't know of a single source which collects together everything about graph eigenvalues, but the text by West has a pretty good chapter introducing the idea.

Comment: Appreciate the responses and ordered the book for supplement!